# Fullcalender is not loaded but loaded on clicking on inspect, ctrl + or ctrl-

Tags: javascript, laravel, fullcalendar

I've integrated the fullcalender plugin version 6.1.10 in a web application from https://fullcalendar.io/. This application is built with Laravel 10. But the fullcalender is not loaded but rather clicking on inspect or ctrl + or ctrl -. I've understood the fullcalender is loaded if the window size of the page is changed. Can anyone please help me?

[image]

[image]

I've written the following code in blade file

```
<div class="tab-pane fade " id="v-pills-calendar" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-calendar-tab">
<!-- Your content for the Bank tab goes here -->
<div class="content">
    <div class="teacherProfile-tab-five">
        <div class="teacher-heading">
            <h1>Calendar</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="calender-content">
            <div class="schedule-button">
                <a href="{{ route('tutor.schedule_lesson') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary d-flex">
                        <p>Schedule a lesson</p>
                        <img src="{{ asset('webapp/assets/images/icons/carbon_add-filled.svg') }}" class="button-icon" loading="lazy" alt="add" />
                    </button></a>
            </div>

            <!-- <div id="calendar-container"></div> -->
            <div id="calendar"></div>
            <div class="calendar-check-boxes d-flex">
                <div class="calendar-cb-one me-5">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="onlineCheckbox" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="onlineCheckbox">
                        Online
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="calendar-cb-two">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="inPersonCheckbox" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inPersonCheckbox">
                        In person
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        initialDate: "{{ date('Y-m-d') }}",
        themeSystem: "bootstrap",
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        events: [{
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2024-02-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2021-02-07',
                end: '2024-02-10'
            },
            {
                groupId: '999',
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2024-02-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                groupId: '999',
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2024-02-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2024-02-11',
                end: '2024-02-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2021-04-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2021-04-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2021-04-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2021-04-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2021-04-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2024-02-24'
            }
        ]
    });

    calendar.render();

});
```

Comment: Did you tried giving a height to the calendar container element ?

Comment: Yes I've added height (<div id="calendar" style="height: 550px;"></div>) but still its not loading. I've also
tried with $( document ).ready() or window.onload in place of DOMContentLoaded but the same issue occurs

Comment: are you implementing it in vuejs ? could you please add a fiddle for  the same

Comment: @AkhilAravind No I'm not implementing in vuejs. Only laravel

Comment: I just created a fiddle and tries, it worked as expected. No issues. Could you please check if console has nay error

Comment: Console doesn't have any error

Comment: ok, my best answer is, change your web browser, try another, or try it in incognito

Comment: I've tested in another browser as well as in incognito but same issue occurs

Comment: You're putting the calendar inside a bootstrap tab, by the looks of it? See the duplicate